# Fractional multiplications - unexpected results of positive numbers

Tags: python, multiplication, fractions

I am getting unexpected results when multiplying 2 fractional numbers.

If i use a calculator (google) to check my sums, i get the correct answer (or the answer i am expecting)

This is an example of the sum i am trying to do
`abs(-0.00012437234926353282 * 0.2)` (Note: the first number is not always negative, but i want the abs result of the sum).

A calculator gives me this answer: 0.00002487446

But python gives me this `2.4874469852706566e-05`

The simple code i am using is this

```
x = y = round(abs(-0.00012437234926353282 * 0.2), 30)
```

I am kind of new to Python, please be kind.

I have tried reading up on it, and lots of methods, including floating, rounding and a few more in combinations and different orders, etc (all clearly wrong methods), but all get the "unexpected" results

Comment: That is literally the same result. The e-0.5 signifies an exponent of -0.5, i.e 10 to the power of -0.5, which translates to 0.00001 being multiplied to the original number, which gives you 0.000024874469852706566.

Comment: @A-T It's `-05`, not `-0.5`. `-0.5` would be the reciprocal of the *square root* instead of the reciprocal of `1e5`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @wjandrea. As you can see, I meant to write e-05 in my explanation but ended up writing -0.5 for some reason unclear to me now too. God knows what I was thinking while writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, python does give the correct result: `2.4874469852706566e-05` means `2.4874469852706566 * 10**(-5)` which is the same as google's result of `0.00002487446`, just rounded to a different decimal place.

Comment: You are correct; the 'e' thing is _scientific notation_

Comment: It's not exactly the same though; the last digit is 6 in Google's result, but the Python result would be rounded to 7 at the same spot.

Comment: @wjandrea I've checked on [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=2%2F3&rlz=1C1ONGR_deDE982DE982&ei=lkL6Y9KIMZ2Bxc8P97yM0Ak&ved=0ahUKEwjSq8bUlrH9AhWdQPEDHXceA5oQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=2%2F3&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEJECMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgkIABAHEB4Q8QQyBggAEAcQHjIFCAAQgAQyBggAEAcQHjIJCAAQBxAeEPEEOgoIABBHENYEELADSgQIQRgAULkEWMkGYK4HaAFwAXgAgAFPiAGZAZIBATKYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), and it seems that it doesn't round numbers, but rather truncates them.

Comment: @user Those comparisons are both `True`. You can plug them right into Python and see that; you don't need to use `if`. Plus, if you plug in `0.00002487446`, Python represents it as `2.487446e-05`.

Comment: OK, thank you. my lack of math understanding then!
So would this be viable code?
if 2.4874469852706566e-05 < 0.001:
    print("less")
else:
    print("more")
it does register as less!
(it just does not register in my mind as less :-) )
What i am doing it making LOTS of calculations, so am outputting the results to check i coded it correct, yet "2.4874469852706566e-05" looked incorrect or not what i was expecting to see!

Comment: Thank you all! It was my mistake (of course always is with code!) even though it didn't look correct in my test output, it was functioning correct! I now know for future that python is better at math than i am :-)